# replace vector using map in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have an vector and a map. And want to replace the vector element if it is an map key (replace the key with value)

```
user=> (def v [:a :b :c :d])
#'user/v
user=> (def m {:a :k, :c :q} )
#'user/m

user=>  (reduce (fn[x y] (conj x (if (y m) (y m) y))) [] v)
[:k :b :q :d]
```

Is there any  better way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your input and output are collections of the same length and the collection items are calculated independently, it would be simpler and more idiomatic to use `map`, or `mapv` for vector output.

```
(mapv (fn [x] (m x x))
      v)
```

or simply

```
(mapv #(m % %) v)
```

Note that `(m x x)` is similar to `(if (contains? m x) (m x) x)`.

Comment: Small correction: `(get m x x)` is equal to `(if (contains? m x) (m x) x)` (see `(get {:x nil} :x :x)`). Also, you can shorten the function to `#(m % %)` since maps implement `IFn` and can thus directly be used for lookup.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that hash-map as function also had a "not-found" value.

Comment: The hash-map as function does not have a default value parameter. The `get` function does.

Comment: Actually, I tested this and it does for me at least: `({1 1} 2 3)` => `3`

Answer (score 1):

[replace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/replace) does exactly what you want :

```
user> (replace {:a :x :b :y} [:a :b :c :d :e :f])
[:x :y :c :d :e :f]
```

Note it works with vectors as an associative collection where keys are indices :

```
user> (replace [:a :b :c :d] [0 2 4 3 2 1])
[:a :c 4 :d :c :b]
```